# unable to create new fields after upgrading masterpage to 2010

Tags: master-pages, sharepoint-2010

0

Hi Guys,

I am unable to create new fields in existing lists after upgrading my 2007 master page to 2010. I get an error which says

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.03; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; MS-RTC LM 8; .NET4.0C)
Timestamp: Mon, 12 Jul 2010 13:47:48 UTC


Message: 'undefined' is null or not an object
Line: 1281
Char: 4
Code: 0
URI: http://sharepoint2010/_layouts/fldNew.aspx?List=%7B94C7D5B0%2D781A%2D44C1%2DA865%2DE3D0C0629EB9%7D
```

My master page is located here http://pastie.org/1040873

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by moving the following tag

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderUtilityContent" runat="server" />
```

outside the form